# cvReleaseImage with cvqueryframe

Tags: opencv

I'm grabbing a frame from an avi video.

```
img1 = cvQueryFrame( capture );   
cvReleaseImage( &img1 );
```

When I try to release the grabbed frame img1, I get

```
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occurred in "
```

How can I release the memory allocated for img1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not! The user is not allowed to release the memory. See [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/highgui_reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cvQueryFrame). Also, img1 may be NULL. So, you should check if it is a valid image or not - before using it.

Comment: So how can i deallocate the memory used at the end? If i'm calling the program multiple times, the memory will keep increasing everytime.

Comment: It will not leak. OpenCV takes care of that. You do not have to worry about memory increasing. If you want to modify the data, though, you must take a copy and work with the copy( and then release it).